# Postgres Encryption of configuration files

Tags: postgresql, encryption

Currently in Postgres the largest security hole is the .conf files that the database relies on, this is because someone with access to the system (not necessarily the database) can modify the files and gain entry.  Because of this I am seeking out resources on how to encrypt those .conf files and then decrypt them during each session of the database.  Performance is not really an issue at this point.  Does anyone have any resources on this or has anyone developed any prototypes that utilize this functionality?

*Edit*

Since there seems to be some confusion here about what it is I am asking.  The scenario can best be illustrated on a Windows box with the following groups:
1) Administrators  `System Administrators`
2) Database Administrators  `Postgres Administrators`
3) Auditors `Security Auditors`

The Auditors group typically needs access to log files and configuration files to ensure system security.  However, the issue comes when a member of the `Auditors` group needs to view the Postgres configuration and log files.  If this member decides that they want to access the database even though they `do not` have a database account it is a very short task to `break in` .  How does one go about preventing this?  Answers such as: `Get better auditors` are quite poor as you can never fully predict what people will do.

Comment: OK, if the db is properly secured then nothing in the config files can be used to gain access, as they'd still need a password to get in.  If you're set to trust connections, then nothing can be done to keep them out, as anyone on the network can sniff the traffic and see that you're connecting in trust mode and emulate / spoof IPs to get in.
If reading your conf files lets people break in then it was hopeless to begin.
If the auditors need write access to the conf files then they're now dbas / sys admins and should be treated as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are fine.  No need to encrypt, so long as you have permissions on the *.conf files correct.

Your postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf should both be marked as readable only by the postgres user/group.  If you don't have actual users with those permissions, then only root can see them.

Comment: I agree, this can easily be controlled via file permissions (btw: at least on Windows there *is* a Postgres user. It is needed to start the service)

Comment: If you are using some service that doesn't have proper file permissions on the database files, then you may even have a bigger problem than just these two files.  Who knows what else they are not locking down properly?  This is something that your provider needs to address directly when you bring it up to them.  If they don't, you have a bigger issue.

Answer (score 2):

So, are you trying to prevent root from making changes?  Cause just a normal user can't change those files, and if you don't trust root, you've already lost.

Comment: +1.  Anyone with enough access to alter the config files can walk off with the entire database.  This isn't a hole in Pg, it's a hole in how it was installed.

Comment: @Blrfl I've updated my post so that you can more fully understand what it is I am getting at.

Comment: The problem is still the same.  If there's sufficient information in the Pg configuration files that someone can gain access to the database just by reading them (e.g., the knowledge that Pg will accept any user connecting from a particular IP), your trust model is too permissive.  It's pretty clear you don't trust your auditors, which is fine.  The only other way to give them access to systems they may damage during an audit is to require that they be supervised by someone you trust.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be stuck - here's what you said:

`The Auditors group typically needs access to log files and configuration files`

and then:

`How does one go about preventing [Auditors from accessing the database using the values in the configuration files]?`

If you really want to let Auditors get at your config files but are nervous about them accessing your database, your best bet would be to move your config files off of your server to somewhere else - and then make sure Auditors don't actually have access to your production systems. They could still look at the log files all they wanted, but they wouldn't be able to access the database server to try to get at the database itself.

Comment: There should be nothing NOTHING in the config files that you could use to gain access.  Or you're doing it wrong.